# Eclipse History icons become red boxes

Tags: eclipse

My **Eclipse History(SVN)** icons become red boxes as blew.

I thought I could fix it using Eclipse plugin files (ex, CSS)
But I don't know where and how to change codes.

It happened as soon as I opened the History panel after installing Eclipse and SVN plugin.
Moreover, I can see the icons when a mouse moves over the icons.

Eclipse and other information

- Eclipse version : `2021-03 (4.19.0)`
- Java version: `11.0.10`
- SVN plugin: `Subversive - SVN Team Provider 4.0.5`
- Theme: `Dark`
- Color and Font theme: `Default`

[image: The red boxes]

[image: Mouseover effect]

Comment: Does the issue remain when switching to a new workspace?

Comment: it remains including other workspaces which I use.

Comment: Please try a fresh workspace without copying the settings: _File > Switch Workspace_.

Comment: I already did it. But it's same. I think it's a SVN plugin problem. Because when I use the history of Git, it works out.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a way to solve it (without having to re-build the plugin from source as described below)?

Comment: I hadn't found it. So I just reinstall everything. Maybe I think it could work as below. But I haven't tried before. Because I don't know how to edit and build Subversive plugin.

Answer (score 1):

If you modify the source code of the Subversive plugin as below and build it, it will work fine. I am hoping someone will build and publish it :)

setHoverImageDescriptor -> setImageDescriptor

```java
protected HistoryAction(String text, String imageDescriptor) {
    this(text);
-   this.setHoverImageDescriptor(imageDescriptor == null ? null : SVNTeamUIPlugin.instance().getImageDescriptor(imageDescriptor));
+   this.setImageDescriptor(imageDescriptor == null ? null : SVNTeamUIPlugin.instance().getImageDescriptor(imageDescriptor));
}
protected HistoryAction(String text, String imageDescriptor, int style) {
    super(SVNUIMessages.getString(text), style);
-   this.setHoverImageDescriptor(imageDescriptor == null ? null : SVNTeamUIPlugin.instance().getImageDescriptor(imageDescriptor));
+   this.setImageDescriptor(imageDescriptor == null ? null : SVNTeamUIPlugin.instance().getImageDescriptor(imageDescriptor));
}
```

https://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/technology/org.eclipse.subversive/trunk/org.eclipse.team.svn.ui/src/org/eclipse/team/svn/ui/history/HistoryActionManager.java

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue (but not same if occurs with fresh workspace): https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1106501/

In short, go to: *Workspace*.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench\

Edit the file workbench.xmi, find and replace all

```
*.gif -> *.png
```